# STM32F103 priorities to handle nested interrupts

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, freertos

I could find a problem related to NVIC_Init in STM32F10x library related to priorities to handle nested interrupts.
We know that any interrupt with a priority value equal or higher than BASEPRI ( 11 in our case)  can call FromISR() FreeRTOS API functions.

FreeRTOS uses 15 level ( the lowest priority).

```
#define configLIBRARY_KERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    15
```

In other words, FreeRTOS allows us to call  API  fuctions ( see  xQueueSendToBackFromISR) from ISR with  15-11 priority. 
When we initialize the NVIC we use level #11

```
#define    WRTU2_DMA1_SPI2_IRQ_PRIORITY     (configLIBRARY_KERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY-4*)
    /* DMA1 Channel4 interrupt setting */
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA1_Channel4_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = WRTU2_DMA1_SPI2_IRQ_PRIORITY;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = WRTU2_DMA1_SPI2_IRQ_PRIORITY;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

So, we should be  OK.  But the problem exists. I decided to check  NVIC_Init.

According to the information from STM32 datasheet the priority register is **0xe000e40e** ( NVIC channel 14 belongs to **DMA1_Channel4** interrupts).

And I could read  **0x00** from that register after NVIC was initialized. It means NVIC channel #14 has the highest priority in the system.

And it causes all problems.

I added the simplest fix     **NVIC->IP[DMA1_Channel4_IRQn] = 0xF0;**
And the system does not fail anymore. So, our current problem is solved.

Of course, I tried to analyze what happens in NVIC_Init

```
**
  * @brief  Initializes the NVIC peripheral according to the specified
  *         parameters in the NVIC_InitStruct.
  * @param  NVIC_InitStruct: pointer to a NVIC_InitTypeDef structure that contains
  *         the configuration information for the specified NVIC peripheral.
  * @retval None
  */
void NVIC_Init(NVIC_InitTypeDef* NVIC_InitStruct)
{
  uint32_t tmppriority = 0x00, tmppre = 0x00, tmpsub = 0x0F;

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_FUNCTIONAL_STATE(NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelCmd));
  assert_param(IS_NVIC_PREEMPTION_PRIORITY(NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority));  
  assert_param(IS_NVIC_SUB_PRIORITY(NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority));

  if (NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelCmd != DISABLE)
  {
    /* Compute the Corresponding IRQ Priority --------------------------------*/    
    tmppriority = (0x700 - ((SCB->AIRCR) & (uint32_t)0x700))>> 0x08;
    tmppre = (0x4 - tmppriority);
    tmpsub = tmpsub >> tmppriority;

    tmppriority = (uint32_t)NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority << tmppre;
    tmppriority |=  NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority & tmpsub;
    tmppriority = tmppriority << 0x04;

    NVIC->IP[NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannel] = tmppriority;

    /* Enable the Selected IRQ Channels --------------------------------------*/
    NVIC->ISER[NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannel >> 0x05] =
      (uint32_t)0x01 << (NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannel & (uint8_t)0x1F);
  }
  else
  {
    /* Disable the Selected IRQ Channels -------------------------------------*/
    NVIC->ICER[NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannel >> 0x05] =
      (uint32_t)0x01 << (NVIC_InitStruct->NVIC_IRQChannel & (uint8_t)0x1F);
  }
}
```

So, I added  the similar  test code to my application  to see how  it converts all values

```
uint32_t NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=0xFF,NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority=0xFF;
int32_t tmppriority = 0x00, tmppre = 0x00, tmpsub = 0x0F;
tprintf("\n\rSCB->AIRCR=0x%08x",SCB->AIRCR);

 tmppriority = (0x700 - ((SCB->AIRCR) & (uint32_t)0x700))>> 0x08;
 tprintf("\n\rtmppriority=0x%08x",tmppriority);
tmppre = (0x4 - tmppriority);
tmpsub = tmpsub >> tmppriority;

 tprintf("\n\rtmppre=0x%08x",tmppre);
 tprintf("\n\rtmpsub=0x%08x",tmpsub);


tmppriority = (uint32_t)NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority << tmppre;
tmppriority |=  NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority & tmpsub;
tmppriority = tmppriority << 0x04;
tprintf("\n\rtmppriority=0x%08x",tmppriority);
```

There is a log

```
SCB->AIRCR=0xfa050000
tmppriority=0x00000007
tmppre=0xfffffffd
tmpsub=0x00000000
tmppriority=0x00000000
```

Note, even I specify 0xFF for both input parameters it returns 0x00.

I am really surprised about that behavior. This is a library function.

People use it for many years. So, I am really confused I can find find the problem in that function.

Maybe it is related to Application interrupt and reset control register (SCB_AIRCR)
Address offset: 0x0C
Reset value: 0xFA05 0000
Required privilege: Privileged
The AIRCR provides priority grouping control for the exception model, endian status for data
accesses, and reset control of the system.

Note, in the library sources I can see `#define AIRCR_VECTKEY_MASK    ((uint32_t)0x05FA0000)`

So, it looks like we have some kind of BIG vs LITTLE ENDIAN byte  order in the 16-bit nibble.

Do you have any suggestion or knowledge about the problem?

Comment: What is the * for at the end of the #define ? Also I don't think you should be using sub priorities. I don't think the FreeRTOS code is setup to use them properly. See the documentation.

Comment: Also you are left shifting by a negative number which is undefined. "tmppriority = (uint32_t)NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority << tmppre;"

Comment: * just for misspelling. 
"Also you are left shifting by a negative number which is undefined. "tmppriority = (uint32_t)NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority << tmppre;" it is a library function which I copy.

Comment: It might be a library function however I am sure that tmppre would not be 0xfffffffd.

Comment: I have found the problem in the following comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the problem is I should use  NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(3); as 3 for the cortex-m3.

then it provides 4-bit preemptive priority and  0 bit for subpriority. At final when I initiliase like that it works as I expected.

```
  /* DMA1 Channel4 interrupt setting */
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA1_Channel4_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 11;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```